# Why won't ".includes" work with my two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

**Intro:** 
For school I have to make a project where it checks the answers of a "test" and if they are correct or not. We have to do this using a two dimensional array and the ".includes" function.

**Required:**

- **MUST** include a ".includes"

**What I've tried:**

- Removing and adding the "i" in both arrays in the if-statement
- Console.log-ing tests to make sure it's not the arrays fault
- Googled to Australia and back

Alright I've recieved some awesome answers however I do not understand what they're doing (even after researching and googling). I've revised my code to make it shorter and easier to read. I still need help.

**What I get:** 
[image]

**Code:**

- HTML:

  ```
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>a test</title>
          <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Answer the questions</h1>
          <div>
              <h3>What is the capital of France?</h3>
              <input type="text" name="capFrance" 
   id="capFrance">
              <br>
              <h3>How many legs does a spider have?</h3>
              <input type="number" name="legSpider" id="legSpider">
              <br>
              <h3>What is the biggest lake in the Netherlands?</h3>
              <input type="text" name="lakeNL" id="lakeNL">
              <br>
              <h3>What is a german Car brand?</h3>
              <input type="text" name="gerBrand" id="gerBrand">
              <br>
              <h3>Name an island</h3>
              <input type="text" name="island" id="island">
              <br><br>
              <button onclick="answerChecker()">Check answers! 
  </button>
          </div>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- JavaScript:

  ```
  function answerChecker() {
  var answersInput = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  var rightAnswers = 
      [
          ["Parijs"],
          ["8]", 
          ["Ijselmeer"],
          ["Volkswagen", "Audi", "Opel", "Porsche", "BMW", "Mercedes", 
  "Mercedes-Benz"],
          ["Texel", "Vlieland", "Terschelling", "Ameland", 
  "Schiermonnikoog"],
      ];

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < rightAnswers.length; i++) {
      if (rightAnswers[i].includes(answersInput[i].value) == 
  true) {
          answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
          answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Edit: I've translated everything to Englihs, I've swapped some code for more effective and clean reading and I've removed the "old" code.

Comment: You'll get a quicker answer if your variables etc are in English.

Comment: @s89_ You got it! Will translate now. :D

Comment: besides the need to use arrays and includes, what are you trying to accomplish ? what is your goal or expected output.

Comment: Seems like `antwoorden` is an array of strings... So `antwoorden[i]` is a string... And `.includes()` is a method to apply on an array. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: @s89_ Requesting variable name translation is not necessary

Comment: @s89_  There ya go I translated it all!

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez  There ya go I translated it all!

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I am trying to get it to check if the answer you put in is correct using a ".includes" function

Comment: The first three elements of your array `rightAnswers` are strings. They don't have a method `includes()`. Look at my post for further changes.

Comment: Change it to: `if (correcteAntwoorden[i].includes(answersInput[i]))`

Comment: @A1rPun thanks! Hadn't seen it! It now only works with the first 3, the last 2 don't work.

Comment: @A1rPun Yeah I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I think it's in the array in the array. Right?

Comment: @Lar I missed multiple changes so my comment was not accurate.

Comment: @A1rPun That's okay, I appreciate all the help you have been giving.

Comment: Other than the `["8]",` typo I can't see why this code won't work.. I'll add it to my answer to see if all cases work.

Comment: @Lar Final comment for me :) I added a working snippet based on your solution

Comment: @A1rPun Same here! Last comment! I am thrilled (that's why I have added multiple exlemation(?) points. IT WORKS! Thank you soooo much!! I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working snippet with changes:

- `["8]",` -> `["8"],`
- `var i` -> `let i`
- omit `== true`

```js
function answerChecker() {
  var answersInput = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  var rightAnswers = [
    ["Parijs"],
    ["8"],
    ["Ijselmeer"],
    ["Volkswagen", "Audi", "Opel", "Porsche", "BMW", "Mercedes",
      "Mercedes-Benz"
    ],
    ["Texel", "Vlieland", "Terschelling", "Ameland",
      "Schiermonnikoog"
    ],
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < rightAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (rightAnswers[i].includes(answersInput[i].value)) {
      answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>a test</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Answer the questions</h1>
  <div>
    <h3>What is the capital of France?</h3>
    <input type="text" name="capFrance" id="capFrance">
    <br>
    <h3>How many legs does a spider have?</h3>
    <input type="number" name="legSpider" id="legSpider">
    <br>
    <h3>What is the biggest lake in the Netherlands?</h3>
    <input type="text" name="lakeNL" id="lakeNL">
    <br>
    <h3>What is a german Car brand?</h3>
    <input type="text" name="gerBrand" id="gerBrand">
    <br>
    <h3>Name an island</h3>
    <input type="text" name="island" id="island">
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="answerChecker()">Check answers! 
</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Old answer

The initial problem is that you do nothing with the different data types in your `rightAnswers` array. This can be fixed in multiple ways but let's assume you can't edit the `rightAnswers` structure.

So let's analyze what you do here:

```
for (i = 0; i < yourAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (yourAnswers[i].includes(rightAnswers[i]) == true) {
        answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

You check if the given answer by the user is the exact same (case-sensitive) as the expected answer. The answer is not always a piece of text because you also have arrays in them so your code fails on 2 of the 5 cases.

Let's add this type check in:

```
for (let i = 0; i < yourAnswers.length; i++) {
    const isRightAnswer = typeof rightAnswers[i] === 'string'
        ? yourAnswers[i].includes(rightAnswers[i])
        : rightAnswers[i].includes(yourAnswers[i]);
    answersInput[i].style.backgroundColor = isRightAnswer ? "green" : "red";
}
```

This will handle both of your types in the `rightAnswers` array.

**More clarification**

Let's look at the data structure you use:

```
var rightAnswers = [
  "Parijs",
  '8',
  "Ijselmeer",
  ["Volkswagen", "Audi", "Opel", "Porsche", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Mercedes-Benz"],
  ["Texel", "Vlieland", "Terschelling", "Ameland", "Schiermonnikoog"],
];
```

You have 3 values which are of type `String` and 2 values which are of type `Array`. So when you access them like this `rightAnswers[i]` you have run different code depending on the type. So that is why I presented a [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) check.

This is the [`String` variant of `includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
yourAnswers[i].includes(rightAnswers[i])
```

This is the [`Array` variant of `includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
rightAnswers[i].includes(yourAnswers[i])
```

You call this a `two dimensional array` but a true `two dimensional array` is an array with only arrays as childs. @CarstenMassmann converted your array to a true one because handling will become much simpler because you only have to worry about one type.

`?:` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and is basically a shorthand `if then else`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question. Would you mind explaining what you're doing here a bit more, since I'm not advanced enough to understand what's going on. Again I appreciatie it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten and simplify your script quite a bit:

- I re-organized the provided answer inputs into a single array `qarr`.
- all correct answers are now in the array `aarr`, which also contains sub-arrays with correct answer options (even for those cases where only one option exists). All answers have been converted to lower case to simplify the comparison.
- the comparison itself with `.includes()` is now trivial ...
- you can un-comment the `document.body.addEventListener("input",checkone);` line to carry out direct checking on input ..

```js
const qarr=[...document.querySelectorAll("input")],
      aarr=[["parijs","paris"],['8'],["ijselmeer"], 
            ["volkswagen", "audi", "opel", "porsche", "bmw", "mercedes","mercedes-benz"],
            ["texel", "vlieland", "terschelling", "ameland","schiermonnikoog"]];

// document.body.addEventListener("input",checkone);
document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>qarr.forEach(a=>checkone({target:a}));
  
function checkone(ev){
 const el=ev.target, i=qarr.indexOf(el); // get el and index of question
 el.style.backgroundColor=aarr[i].includes(el.value.trim().toLowerCase())?"green":"red";
}
```

```html
<h1>Answer the questions</h1>
<div>
  <h3>What is the capital of France?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="capFrance" id="capFrance">
  <br>
  <h3>How many legs does a spider have?</h3>
  <input type="number" name="legSpider" id="legSpider">
  <br>
  <h3>What is the biggest lake in the Netherlands?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="lakeNL" id="lakeNL">
  <br>
  <h3>What is a german Car brand?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="gerBrand" id="gerBrand">
  <br>
  <h3>Name an island</h3>
  <input type="text" name="island" id="island">
  <br><br>
  <button>Check answers!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very nice and in depht(?) answer. I tried it and it worked! Though our schools checking system will not allow it, since there is no proper use of the ".includes". 

I love the way you formatted your answer and appreciate the clarifications sincerely. thank you again.

Comment: The `.includes()` call is the central part of it all. How will this not be "allowed"?!? It shows again that some "automatic scoring/checking systems" are not good at all ;-).

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed. Oops, so much advanced language! :D I appreciate it. Will try again.